# Install Oxalis AS4 for Peppol

Tags: tomcat, oxalis

I completed building Oxalis AS2. Now I implement AS4 for Oxalis server.

I try to follow the guide here https://github.com/difi/Oxalis-AS4 but have no clue for the following items:
1. Where is the "ext" folder located in the following guide?

> Oxalis server comes out of the box with a folder for extensions (named
>   "ext"). Extract the content of oxalis-as4-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT-dist.zip into
>   this folder. No further configuration is needed.

2. Where is the config xml file of Tomcat in the following guide?

> We have added an example deployment XML file for tomcat 8+. Ensure
>   that your file locations match with the paths in the XML.

Thank you for taking a look at my question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally know what are they.
You can follow this document [enter link description here](https://github.com/difi/Oxalis-AS4/blob/master/docs/Tomcat.md)

In details:
1. Where is the "ext" folder located in the following guide?

> Oxalis server comes out of the box with a folder for extensions (named
>   "ext"). Extract the content of oxalis-as4-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT-dist.zip into
>   this folder. No further configuration is needed.

Just put the file in a folder and refer that folder in the second step.

2. Where is the config xml file of Tomcat in the following guide?

> We have added an example deployment XML file for tomcat 8+. Ensure
>   that your file locations match with the paths in the XML.

The file is in tomcat config: /conf/Catalina/localhost/oxalis.xml.
Or you can change oxalis.xml name as your path config.